# DataTable.Select Words Starting Between Two Letters

Tags: select, datatable, ado.net, datarow

I'd like to select all `DataRows` in my `DataTable` where the word in the column begins between two characters, eg `A` to `H`.

I've tried

```
DataTable.Select("'LastName' BETWEEN 'A' AND 'H'");
DataTable.Select("'LastName' >= 'A' AND 'LastName' <= 'H'");
DataTable.Select("'LastName' LIKE '^[A-H]*.$]'");
```

And none seem to work. I get errors such as the following.

```
The expression contains unsupported operator 'Between'.
Error in Like operator: the string pattern '^[A-H]*.$]' is invalid.
```

What is the correct way of fetching names that begin between two letters? Or words that begin between two letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable.Select("SUBSTRING([Last Name],1,2) >= 'A' AND SUBSTRING([Last Name],1,2) < 'I'");
```

does the trick but isn't very elegant.